# Making a subquery with a set of dates (sundays) between two points

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I need to form several subqueries with sets of dates including only sundays between two set points, for example between 01.04.2018 and 30.06.2018.

The first thing which comes into mind is something like this:

```
SELECT '01.04.2018' STARTDATE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '08.04.2018' STARTDATE FROM DUAL
...
```

But it doesn't look very elegant. Is there an easier way to achieve what I need?

Comment: do you mean you want identify only sunday dates between 2 dates?

Comment: And post table structures and is the column date/time?  Or just date and do you want unique dates (if times included)?

Comment: do you have a proper date dimension table?

Comment: this would be alot easier by referencing a date dimension table and just pull back records where the day is a sunday and falls between your target dates

Comment: consider a proper date dimension table https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: @jimmy8ball This is not an SQL Server question.

Comment: I'm also not a DBA so I can't make any new tables. Read-only rights.

Comment: A date dimension is not specific to sql server

Comment: @jimmy8ball A dimension table is unnecessary as you can just use a recursive sub-query factoring clause (a.k.a. CTE) or a hierarchical query and do not need to perform disk IO to access a table or worry that the dimension table's bounds are insufficient for your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/473)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY( DATE '2018-04-01' - 1, 'SUNDAY' ) + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7
         AS startdate
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY
       NEXT_DAY( DATE '2018-04-01' - 1, 'SUNDAY' ) + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7
         <= DATE '2018-06-30'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/473/0)**:

```
|            STARTDATE |
|----------------------|
| 2018-04-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-04-08T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-04-15T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-04-22T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-04-29T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-05-06T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-05-13T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-05-20T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-05-27T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-06-03T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-06-10T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-06-17T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-06-24T00:00:00Z |
```

> Does this construction always return at least one row? If I add an additional condition that `NEXT_DAY( DATE '2018-07-01' - 1, 'SUNDAY' ) + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7` should be less than `SYSDATE` it still returns the first row which is larger than `SYSDATE`.

Yes, a hierarchical query will always return one row if the filtering is just performed in the `CONNECT BY` clause (since it will only check it when it tries to connect one row to its parent and needs to have generated at least one parent first to do this):

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY( DATE '2018-07-01' - 1, 'SUNDAY' ) + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7
         AS startdate
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY
       NEXT_DAY( DATE '2018-07-01' - 1, 'SUNDAY' ) + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7
         <= LEAST(
              SYSDATE, -- DATE '2018-06-29'
              DATE '2018-07-30'
            )
```

**Results**:

```
|            STARTDATE |
|----------------------|
| 2018-07-01T00:00:00Z | -- Greater than SYSDATE
```

But if you add a `WHERE` clause (rather than filtering in the `CONNECT BY` clause) then it can return zero rows:

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY( DATE '2018-07-01' - 1, 'SUNDAY' ) + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7
         AS startdate
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  NEXT_DAY( DATE '2018-07-01' - 1, 'SUNDAY' ) + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7
         <= SYSDATE
CONNECT BY
       NEXT_DAY( DATE '2018-07-01' - 1, 'SUNDAY' ) + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7
         <= DATE '2018-07-30'
```

**Results**:

```
No data found.
```

Comment: Not only it solves the problem, but also introduces me to recurcion in SQL :) Thanks!

Comment: does this construction always return at least one row? If I add an additional condition that `NEXT_DAY( DATE '2018-07-01' - 1, 'SUNDAY' ) + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7` should be less than SYSDATE it still returns the first row which is larger than SYSDATE.

Comment: @User24112017 Updated

Answer (score 0):

The brute force approach would be to just generate the entire date range and then filter it to leave only Sundays:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TRUNC (date '2018-06-30' - ROWNUM) dt
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 100
)

SELECT * FROM cte WHERE TO_CHAR(dt, 'DAY') = 'SUN'
```

Comment: Why exactly 99 rows? What happens if I want 2 years worth of Sundays? Why not use the OP's date boundary rather than an arbitrary magic number?

Comment: @MT0 I don't have your Oracle skills.  This is the best I could do.

Comment: `CONNECT BY TRUNC (date '2018-06-30' - ROWNUM) >= DATE '2018-04-01'` would get rid of the magic number and use the OP's date boundary.